# Detached entities immutable list attributes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, jpa-2.0, openjpa

In OpenJPA 2.2 when i detach some entity, all the list attributes are "readonly (immutables) i cannot change them, but i could change some other attribute like a String".

Is this the normal behavior for list attributes in any entity? or is just a limitation of openjpa, what have to be the normal behavior that the specification says?

**ENTITIES**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

   @Id
   private int id;
   private String userName;
   private String password;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
   private List<Role> roles;

   //getters and setters..

}


@Entity 
public class Role implements Serializable{

   @Id
   private int id;
   private String roleName;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;

  //getters and setters..
}
```

**EJB INTERFACE LOCAL**

```
@Local
public interface MyEJBLocal{
   public User getUserWithRoles();
}
```

**EJB CLASS**

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName ="ANY_NAME")
    private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public User getUser(){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

        cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.userName),"john"));

       User user = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult());
       em.detach(user); //detaching user object
       return user;
  }

}
```

**MANAGED BEAN**

```
@Named
public class MyBean implements Serializable{

 @EJB
 private MyEJBLocal ejb;

 public void anyMethod(){
   User user = ejb.getUser();
   //i will create a list of role just for try to set any role the userJohn
      List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<Role>(2);
      roleList.add(new Role(1,'ADMIN'); //creating and adding role 1
      roleList.add(new Role(2,'DEVELOPER');//creating and adding role 2

     //setting the list of roles created to the user, as you can see the list has 2 values but the value roles of userJohn always is set to null, my setters and getters are correct
     userJohn.setRoles(roleList);

    user.getRoles(); //<---- HERE THE LIST IS ALWAYS NULL

    user.setUserName("new_name");//<--- But this works

 }
}
```

What i have to do is clone my entity for add or change list values. Somebody recommends my to use DTO for this, but im not sure what can i do.

I will appreciate any comments.

Comment: You are calling the setter on userJohn, but getter on user. Just a typo? And similarly, interface defines getUserWithRoles(), but bean implements getUser().

Comment: @Mareen its only a typo

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of detaching, you have to maintain both sides of the relationship.

Java Persistence 2.0, Final Release:

> It is the developer’s responsibility to keep the in-memory references
>   held on the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent
>   with each other when they change.

During persist the owning side is what is stored to db.

> Relationships may be bidirectional or unidirectional. A bidirectional
>   relationship has both an owning side and an inverse (non-owning) side.
>   A unidirectional relationship has only an owning side. The owning side
>   of a relationship determines the updates to the relationship in the
>   database, as described in section
>   3.2.4.
>
> ...
>
> The many side of one-to-many / many-to-one bidirectional relationships
>   must be the owning side, hence the mappedBy element cannot be
>   specified on the ManyToOne annotation.

In your case the Role entity is the owning side.

Btw. user and role usually have a many to many relationship.

Comment: Yes but im not trying to persist, i just want add a new list in my mangedbean for a merge operation. The list is never changed is immutable!!. I know about the bidirectional FK it just an example and by the way about roles and user is only an idea.

Comment: when i detached and object the list have to be immutable? i cannot find something in the specification that sayed that list have to be immutables!

Comment: @maxtorzito: no the list should not be immutable. If you really call the setter with a non-null value and then immediately call the getter, you should get the non-null value. I doubt there is such a bug in OpenJPA 2.2, but I cannot verify this. You should consider posting more of your code.

Comment: @maxtorzito: as a side not - when you call detach the way you do, only the User is detached, its roles are not fetched yet due to lazy loading and therefore they cannot be detached. Once they get fetched they will be in attached state.